# Decile function in R - nested ifelse() statements lead to poor runtime

Tags: r, statistics, quantile

I wrote a function that calculates the deciles of each row in a vector.  I am doing this with the intention of creating graphics to evaluate the efficacy of a predictive model.  There has to be a easier way to do this, but I haven't been able to figure it out for a while.  Does anyone have any idea how I could score a vector in this way without having so many nested ifelse() statements?  I included the function as well as some code to copy my results.

```
# function
decile <- function(x){
  deciles <- vector(length=10)
  for (i in seq(0.1,1,.1)){
    deciles[i*10] <- quantile(x, i)
  }
  return (ifelse(x<deciles[1], 1,
         ifelse(x<deciles[2], 2,
                ifelse(x<deciles[3], 3,
                       ifelse(x<deciles[4], 4,
                              ifelse(x<deciles[5], 5,
                                     ifelse(x<deciles[6], 6,
                                            ifelse(x<deciles[7], 7,
                                                  ifelse(x<deciles[8], 8,
                                                         ifelse(x<deciles[9], 9, 10))))))))))
}

# check functionality
test.df <- data.frame(a = 1:10, b = rnorm(10, 0, 1))

test.df$deciles <- decile(test.df$b)

test.df

# order data frame
test.df[with(test.df, order(b)),]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `quantile` and `findInterval`

```
# find the decile locations 
decLocations <- quantile(test.df$b, probs = seq(0.1,0.9,by=0.1))
# use findInterval with -Inf and Inf as upper and lower bounds
findInterval(test.df$b,c(-Inf,decLocations, Inf))
```

Comment: this seems to work fine but i'm gonna work my way through it real quickly and make sure I understand it.  I've never used findInterval() before.

Comment: mnel's answer works perfectly.

@Matthew, the `all.inside=T` option does not work because the decLocations vector only goes up to the 90th percentile.  If you want to use all.inside you would need to change the first line to:

`decLocations <- quantile(test.df$b, probs = seq(0.1,1,by=0.1))`

Comment: You are correct, Zap (as is mnel).  I missed that he changed the parameter to `seq`.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use `ecdf()`, described in the help files as the inverse of `quantile()`.

```
round(ecdf(test.df$b)(test.df$b) * 10)
```

Note that @mnel's solution is around 100 times faster.